# add Multiple classes in a PHP echo statement

Tags: php, css, class, echo

Hi I am trying to add more than one class whilst echoing some html but it Just does not seem to work. the PHP looks like the following:

```
echo
"<div class="."alert alert-success"." role="."alert".">
        <strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.
</div>";
```

the output looks like this (captured using dev tools on chrome):

```
<div class="alert" alert-success="" role="alert">
        <strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.
</div>
```

It has autofilled the ="" on the alert-success but it looks like this officially

```
<div class="alert" alert-success role="alert">
        <strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.
</div>
```

For some reason the alert-success class appears to be put in after the brackets. I have tried moving around the `"` but it remains in the same place. is there something simple I am missing.

Comment: read this: [Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo
  "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>
    <strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.
 </div>";
```

Comment: As per usual i missed an extremely basic thing, thanks. Will accept it when timers off :)

Answer (score 2):

The real output is :

```
<div class=alert alert-success role=alert>
        <strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.
</div>
```

The reason to this is simple : strings in PHP are enclosed by double quotes, and in your code you never put double quotes in the string : you use them to close the string.

To use a double quote in a PHP string enclosed by double quotes, you need to escape the character, by adding a backslash before it :

```
echo
"<div class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\">
        <strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.
</div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with -

```
echo
"<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>
        <strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.
</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is double code and single code so that is wont work. If you want to use double code us backslash.

class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\"

This is run successfully thanks.

"**Well done!** You successfully read this important alert message";